# Unescape a string with escaped sequences in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, escaping, delphi-5

I use Delphi 5 and have a String like this from a http-connection:

```
str :='content=bell=7'#$8'size=20'#$8'other1'#$D#$A#$8'other2'
```

This string contains some sequence with escape characters and i want to unescape these characters. If I use the trim function, the escape sequence are still inside. Maybe this is because '#$8' is no viewable sign?

How can i replace '#&8' separately. For example with '&', so that i get the string:

```
str1 :='content=bell=7&size=20&other1'#$D#$A'&other2'
```

After this I can use trim to unescape the other sequences.

```
str2 :='content=bell=7&size=20&other1#13#10&other2'
```

Comment: If D5 has StringReplace: `str1 := StringReplace(str, ''#$8'', '&', [rfReplaceAll]);`

Comment: You don't need the quotes on the second parameter: `str1 := StringReplace(str, #$8, '&', [rfReplaceAll]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are Delphi character sequences. The *compiler* interprets them as it processes your source file. It converts `#$8` into a backspace character in the string. If you want to replace that character with something else, you could call `StringReplace`. (If that's your real code, then you could just skip the extra function call and use the desired characters in the string literal directly in your code.)

```
str2 := StringReplace(str1, #8, '&', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

`Trim` removes whitespace from the start and end of a string, but your characters aren't at either end.

Comment: Thx, that helps. :) I think, i had some understanding problems with Character Escaping in Delphi.